# SSIS: Derived Column, IF Column has ":" Keep String Left of ":", Else Keep The Same

Tags: if-statement, ssis, expression, derived

I have a dir of Excel files in different formats.  I have a derived column with the following expression:

```
FINDSTRING([F4], ":", 1) ? TOKEN([F4], ":", 1) : [F4]
```

I don't believe this is the correct syntax because is producing errors.

The following is my psudocode:

```
"If column contains a ":" then keep everything left of the ":", else, keep the same"
```

What is wrong with my syntax in my Derived Column expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `TOKEN(F4,":",1)` sufficed.